# Polyfit is returning 'nan' while x and y doesn't have 'nan' or 'inf' values in Python

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I am having issue with polyfit and not able to figure out the solution. I have a log-log plot where I try to do polyfit. Neither the 'x' nor 'y' has any 'nan' or 'inf' values. And when I run polyfit, all I get is nan

```
  np.polyfit(x,y,1)
```

result

```
  array([nan, nan])
```

Wondering what the reason be. The x and y I use are of size 524288, so difficult to share. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using the original values or the log of those values? If you have any values <= 0 you will end up with infs or nans, which polyfit will not be able to fit.

Comment: Hi Luke19, thanks you so much. I checked and 'y' have negative values. I cross checked with one that was working, and it seems to be the issue. But I am not getting non convergence message like @Mr.T said, so not entirely sure if that was the issue. Will post if I solve.